# Copy only updated contents from 5 log files and append to an existing file in Java every hour

Tags: java

How to copy only updated contents from 5 log files and append to an existing file in Java every hour?

I have researched a lot but no luck.
Could anyone please help me on this and post the relevant code so that it would be very much helpful for me.

Comment: Not really a job for Java. Java's not really fit for daemon tasks. You need a cron job or a Windows scheduled task

Comment: Keep track of the length of each file, so you know from what point to start copying.  But exactly what kind of copy you want is unclear:  do you want the copied log entries to all be in date order?  Do you want to interleave the contents of the five log files?  Or will you just copy chunks of each log as is?